# creating test users - method is not supported for native application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a test user for my facebook web application. (apps.facebook.com/`<myappname>`).

I browsed my firefox browser to the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<app_id>/accounts/test-users?installed=true&access_token=<app_id>|<app_secret>
```

I got the following result:

{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "(#15) This method is not supported for native apps"
   }
}

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your application is configured correctly in http://www.facebook.com/developers? (See [Canvas Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/))

Have you tried using the application access token? To get this use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

substituting YOUR_APP_ID & YOUR_APP_SECRET with your respective values.

This will return a valid access token that you can substitute for APP_ACCESS_TOKEN in:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=FULL_NAME&method=post&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: I tried your exact method. used the graph api to create an access token, then used that access token but I got the same error message.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the application is configured correctly as a *Facebook Application* at http://www.facebook.com/developers? And is not configured as a mobile application?

Comment: Check under *About* -> *Advanced* to make sure it's a web app.

Comment: you are correct. my app was setup as a desktop app. thanks a lot :)