# Registering an achivement

Tags: facebook-graph-api, native

I'm trying to learn about facbeook achievements, so i made the achivement URL but now when i'm trying to register it i'm getting : 
"(#15) This method is not supported for native apps",

i comlpetely removed the native iOS section from my app's definition on facebook but it still won't let me register.  any ideas?

Oded

Comment: this is the achivement, btw  - 
http://adventuremob.com/fb/test.html

Answer (score 0):

See the following links:
[creating test users - method is not supported for native application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075613/creating-test-users-method-is-not-supported-for-native-application)
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=90782

Also ensure your app is registered as a "game".

Comment: it is and was registered as a game. but still getting this error.